# Quantstrat: sell at next bar (custom)

Tags: trading, algorithmic-trading, quantstrat

I am working on modifying the built-in functions in quantstrat which are related to stop-limits. I want to test a system which sells only when closing price is below the stoplimit. I was able to change the comparison data so it sells when `close < stoplimit`.

However, the sale transaction occurs on the same day that the close triggers the sale. This is a problem I'm working on.

**How to change this code to sell on the next day?**

```
 if(orderType == 'stoplimit')
                         txnprice <- min(orderPrice, Op(mktdataTimestamp)[,1])
                     else
                         txnprice <- orderPrice
                     txntime = timestamp
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the code I used to control order price:

```
txnprice = try(getPrice(x=mktdata[curIndex+1L], prefer=prefer)[,1])
```

The +1L adds a day before the getPrice acts on the curIndex. This is nice because it also takes prefer.

I haven't figured out how to change txntime to the next market day. I can just delay it a day:

```
txntime = timestamp+1
```

Answer (score 0):

A message from Ilya Kipnis:

The ordertype argument is the order type. For most of my demos that I’ve presented thus far, I’ve mostly used “market” type orders, which are the simplest. Market orders execute at the next bar after receiving the signal. They do not execute on the signal bar, but the bar after the signal bar. On daily data, this might cause some P/L due to gaps, but on intraday data, the open of the next bar should be very similar to the close of current bar. One thing to note is that using monthly data, quantstrat uses current-bar execution.